# Get Number Of new users in grafana stat

Tags: grafana

Hi i want to see number of new borrowers in grafana stat panel and also when i select date range from filter then data will accordingly change.
My Database - MySql

And

Below is the screen shot i attached which contains my grafana query, date selected is last 5 years
and also screenshot contains the details of query result.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Query will be this and in right sidebar panel settings made below changes

[image]